# How to repeat a row N times based on a value within the row

Tags: mysql, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file containing three columns, `class,malecount and femalecount` as an input table.

[image]

My output should contain two columns named `Class and Gender`.
The `malecount and femalecount` values indicates how many times a row should be repeated. i.e. for `Class = A and malecount=2`, the row (A,M) should appear twice, and for `Class = C and femalecount=3`, the row (C,F) should appear three times. Check the following image to see the full output.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFtX6.png)

DDL & DML for the table:

```
create table mytable (class text, malecount int, femalecount int);

insert into mytable (class, malecount, femalecount) values
( 'A',2,1),
('B',3,1),
('C',0,3),
('D',2,4);
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
  -- define maximal amount of rows per class per gender to be generated
cte1 AS ( SELECT MAX(GREATEST(malecount, femalecount)) max_count
          FROM test),
  -- generate natural numbers till max. amount found above
cte2 AS ( SELECT 1 num
          UNION ALL
          SELECT num+1 
          FROM cte1
          CROSS JOIN cte2
          WHERE cte2.num <= cte1.max_count)
  -- generate rows for male
SELECT test.class, 'm' gender
FROM test
JOIN cte2 ON cte2.num <= test.malecount
UNION ALL
  -- generate rows for female
SELECT test.class, 'f'
FROM test
JOIN cte2 ON cte2.num <= test.femalecount
  -- final sorting
ORDER BY gender DESC, class
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=694dbb214e4c0cd5524800c56a02dc65

Answer (score 0):

I used the LPAD function and then trimmed off the last comma
from there I had a comma delimited string like M,M,M and F,F

then I used json_table to extract the M,M,M into three rows and the F,F into two rows etc.

here is the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jEXes6AttKvc9GKx1mKY2/1

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
create table mytable (class text, malecount int, femalecount int);

insert into mytable (class, malecount, femalecount) values
( 'A',2,1),
('B',3,1),
('C',0,3),
('D',2,4);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with t as (select class, 
LPAD(' ', malecount * 2 + 1, 'M,') malecount,
LPAD(' ', femalecount * 2 + 1, 'F,') femalecount
from mytable),
t2 as(
select class,
LEFT(malecount,length(malecount)-1) malecount,
LEFT(femalecount,length(malecount)-1) femalecount
from t)
select t2.class, j.name
from t2
join json_table(
  replace(json_array(t2.malecount), ',', '","'),
  '$[*]' columns (name varchar(50) path '$')
) j where j.name = 'M'
union all
select t2.class, k.name
from t2
join json_table(
  replace(json_array(t2.femalecount), ',', '","'),
  '$[*]' columns (name varchar(50) path '$')
) k where k.name = 'F';
```

| class | name |
| --- | --- |
| A | M |
| A | M |
| B | M |
| B | M |
| B | M |
| D | M |
| D | M |
| A | F |
| B | F |
| D | F |
| D | F |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jEXes6AttKvc9GKx1mKY2/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Recursive CTE` as the following:

```
with recursive cte as
(
  select *,0 as repeats  from
  (select class, malecount as cnt, 'M' as Gender from Tbl
    union
    select class, femalecount as cnt, 'F' as Gender from Tbl
   ) D
  union all
  select class,cnt,Gender, repeats+1 from cte
  where repeats<cnt-1
  )
  select class, gender from cte 
  where cnt>0
  order by gender desc,class;
```

See a demo from *[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6L5Kpb5a14Z5VMXvtw4GzD/0)*.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the  function,the expression:

CASE input_expression
WHEN when_expression THEN
result_expression [...n ] [
ELSE
else_result_expression

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).